# laravel query doesnt return right order values using json ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In a laravel controller i have this code

```
 public function CreatGegAjax($id)
{        
    $cities = \App\City::where("nomos_id",$id)->orderBy('name','asc')->get()->pluck('name','id')->prepend('Please select', '');

    return json_encode($cities);
```

In the view i have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="nomos_id"]').on('change', function() {
        var nomosID = $(this).val();

        if(nomosID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/gegonos/ajax/'+nomosID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",                    
                success:function(data) {   

                    $('select[name="city_id"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                        $('select[name="city_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });                                            
                }                    
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="city_id"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

When i select a different state (nomos in greek) nomos_id the dropdown list of the cities changes but it doesnt have the values with the right order asc by name. Where is the mistake?
for example i have the cities

```
id     city         nomos
1      Athens       Attiki
2      Peristeri    Attiki  
3      Marousi      Attiki
4      Salonica     Thessaloniki
```

And when i choose nomos Attiki it must show

```
Please select
Athens
Marousi    
Peristeri
```

Instead of this it shows

```
Athens
Peristeri
Marousi
Please select
```

I cant't find the mistake. thanks

Comment: in the controller before json_encode try to print the result and check whether it is in correct order or not]

Comment: i use dd($cities) or var_dump($cities) before return json_encode($cities) but it doesnt show anything. I think the query is right i used before.

Comment: then why is it not printing the collections??

Comment: i dont know this is why i asked the question. how can i see the results of the cities before the jason return? in the console or with a message like alert?

Comment: are you getting the dropdown now?? in the blade?

Comment: You invoked the request through AJAX, therefore `dd($cities);` would show in Dev tools network module

Comment: when i use this query using a static value in nomosid it works right. When i use it as i wrote in the question has problem

Comment: The problem is orderby('name', 'asc'). It sorts by id not by name but i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to Remove the

```
->prepend('Please select', '')
```

from the controller and after this you to replace

```
pluck('name','id') with pluck('id','name')
```

like this

```
$cities = \App\City::where("nomos_id",$id)->orderBy('name')->pluck('id','name');
```

and change jQuery and reverse key and value!

Like this

```
 $('select[name="city_id"]').append('<option value="">Please select</option>');

 $.each(data, function(key, value) {

 $('select[name="city_id"]').append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ key +'</option>');**strong text**
```

I did it and worked. JhumanJ gave me the idea in [laracasts discussions](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/orderby-problem-sort-by-id-not-by-name).